qiskit DraperQFTAdder
my code:
import itertools
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.circuit.library import DraperQFTAdder
backend = AerSimulator()
adder = DraperQFTAdder(3).decompose()
for l in list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=6)):
    qc = QuantumCircuit(6)
    for i, bit in enumerate(l):
        if bit == 1: 
            qc.x(i)
    qc.append(adder, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    qc = qc.reverse_bits()
    qc.measure_all()
    job = backend.run(transpile(qc, backend), shots=1024)
    print(f"Input: {l}. Result: {job.result().get_counts()}")

results:
Input: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0). Result: {'000000': 1024}   correct
...(some correct parts is ignored)
Input: (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1). Result: {'001000': 1024}   incorrect
...
Input: (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1). Result: {'001010': 1024}   incorrect
Input: (0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0). Result: {'001101': 1024}   correct
Input: (0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1). Result: {'001100': 1024}   incorrect
Input: (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0). Result: {'001111': 1024}   ...
Input: (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1). Result: {'001110': 1024}   ...
Input: (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0). Result: {'010010': 1024}
Input: (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1). Result: {'010011': 1024}
Input: (0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0). Result: {'010001': 1024}
Input: (0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1). Result: {'010000': 1024}
...(results below are ignored)

question:
I'm trying to use DraperQFTAdder to add 2 3-bit numbers, but I got some unexpected results.
I discovered using qc.reverse() from another post on StackExchange. It solved some problems, but not all. I guess the order of qubit is different from which I supposed, which leads to my problem. I wonder how qiskit ranks their qubits in DraperQFTAdder, and how to use this function correctly.

From my experience, it is too unpractical to follow the qubit mapping, you might prefer to use a higher language such as QMOD by Classiq. It allows you to handle quantum variables without being aware of the qubit indexing level. you can check the examples: https://github.com/Classiq/classiq-library/tree/main/functions/function_usage_examples/arithmetic

Thank you @Egretta.Thula for answering my question.
Here I give my code to solve this problem. I hope it will help someone who meet the same problem.
'''
for l in list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=6)):
    qc = QuantumCircuit(6)

    for i, bit in enumerate(l):
        if bit == 1: 
            qc.x(i)
    qc.append(adder, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    qc.measure_all()
    summand1 = 0
    for i in range(3):
        if l[i] == 1: 
            summand1 += 2**(i)
    summand2 = 0
    for i in range(3):
        if l[i+3] == 1: 
            summand2 += 2**(i)
    sum = 0
    job = backend.run(transpile(qc, backend), shots=1024)
    res_dict = job.result().get_counts()
    res_sum = res_dict.most_frequent()
    sum = 0
    for i in range(3):
        if res_sum[i] == '1': 
            sum += 2**(2-i)
    print(f"{summand1} + {summand2} = {sum}")

'''
And here're the result:
'''
0 + 0 = 0
0 + 4 = 4
0 + 2 = 2
0 + 6 = 6
0 + 1 = 1
0 + 5 = 5
0 + 3 = 3
...
7 + 6 = 5
7 + 1 = 0
7 + 5 = 4
7 + 3 = 2
7 + 7 = 6
'''

By default, DraperQFTAdder performs addition modulo $2^n$ where $n$ is the number of state qubits (in your case $n = 3$.) It stores the summation in the qubits used to input the second summand, while the first summand appears at the output without modification.
For example, in the following line
Input: (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0). Result: {'001111': 1024}

you are adding $4 + 3$. The summation is $7$. We should expect the result to be $001111$. The first three digits are the binary representation for the first summand and the next three digits are the binary representation of the summation.
Another example,
Input: (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1). Result: {'001110': 1024}

Here, you are adding $4 + 7$. The summation is $11$. The result is $001110$. Again, the first three digits are the binary representation for the first summand and the next three digits are the binary representation of the summation modulo $8$ (which equals $3$).
You can find more details about DraperQFTAdder and other Qiskit adders here.
